# How to get key from Azure KeyVault as a plain text?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have created key in Key Vault and manually imported private key in it. Now I want to retrieve using shell programing.

I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getkey/getkey and trying to retrieve the plain text but I am getting below error

```
curl https://test-poc-kv-31.vault.azure.net/keys/sftp/ec8368364d1844c908234396e8f50344e68?api-version=7.1
{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."}}
```

Not sure how to get the Bearer token for my URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, `Request is missing a Bearar or Pop token`.

**Steps to create the token:**

1. create a service principal using this command -

```sh
az ad sp create-for-rbac
```

grab `appId` from the output command and provide permissions to this service principal :

[image]

[image]

2. Grab `password`, `appId` and `tenant` from the above command and replace with the following:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={appId}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={password}' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://vault.azure.net/.default'
```

3. Get access_token from the responding command and pass it to this command:

   ```sh
   curl -s "https://test-poc-kv- 
   31.vault.azure.net/keys/sftp/ec8368364d1844c908234396e8f50344e68?api-version=7.1" -H 
   "Authorization: Bearer %access_token%"
   ```

**instead of using curl, you can use Azure CLI ( and make your life much easier )** :

```sh
az keyvault key show --name "%KEY_NAME%" --vault-name "VAULT_NAME"
```

Comment: In my case I have already provided access policy for my VM. Do you know how to get appId,password and tenant id?

Comment: I used managed token in your 3rd step but I could get my actual key that I added in the key in KeyVault  `( curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net' -H Metadata:true -s )`

Comment: With my command I got the expected response `curl -s https://test-poc-kv-01.vault.azure.net/keys/sftp/ec836864d1844c9082396e8f50344e68?api-version=7.1 -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN_ID_FROM_METADAT_URL_IDENTITY>"`. Thanks much I have almost reached the point. Now how to decrypt /unwrap ?

Comment: I am trying to unwap , but I am not able to do :(
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/rest/api/keyvault/unwrapkey/unwrapkey?view=cntk-py-2.3

`curl -d '{"alg": "RSA1_5","value":"RESPONSE_FROM_ABOVECOMMAND"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://test-poc-kv-01.vault.azure.net/keys/sftp/ec836864d1844c908322396e8f50344e68`
Error  Response :    `{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."}}`

Comment: Above issue resolved. Now I am getting `Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.` in response.

Comment: Please accept this answer since it does answer your question, i saw you open a new question regarding the new error. i will look for an answer an provide it over there.